# How can i change hover submenu location?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

[image]

[image]

I did a hover navbar menu, but it isn't working very well. Menu need appear to left side but its appearing on other menus ( down side ) .

I tried put " dropstart "  and margin-left but isn't worked. Position isn't changing.

HTML

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto py-0 me-n3">

    <!--    <img src="img/20yilpng.png" class="yil20" alt=""> -->

        <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link active">Anasayfa</a>

        <div class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-auto-close="outside" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Ürünler</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu m-0">
                        
                <li class="dropstart drophover1">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Yangın & Gaz Algılama Sistemleri </a> 
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownsub ">

                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item"> Adresli Yangın Algılama Sistemleri</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item"> Konvensiyonel Yangın Algılama Sistemleri</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item"> Söndürme Kontrol Sistemleri</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item"> Hava Örneklemeli Duman Algılama Sistemleri</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item"> Doğrusal Kablo Tipi Yangın Dedektörleri</a></li>
                        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="" class="dropdown-item"> Acil Durum Aydınlatma ve Yönlendirme Armatürleri</a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
```

CSS

```css
.dropdown-menu {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: black;
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
    .navbar .drophover1 .dropdownsub{ display: none; }
    .navbar .drophover:hover .dropdownsub{   }
    .navbar .drophover1:hover .dropdownsub{ display:block; }
    .navbar .drophover1 .dropdownsub{ margin-right: 400px; }
}
```